# intersection of stabilizers of block systems

Tags: group-theory

Lets assume the following situation:

$G$ acts regularly on a set $M$. Then there is a bijection between the set of subgroups and the set of blocks containing a fixed element $m \in M$. The blocks can be completed to blocksystems. Now we can compute the Stabilzer $S^B:=Stab_{S_M}(B)$ of a blocksystem $B$. $S^B$ is isomorphic to $S_X \wr S_{|B|}$ where $X$ is a block in $B$. $S^B$ contains $G$ of course. What i would like find is a minimal set of subgroups $U_i$ of $G$, so that $G$ is the intersection of the stabilizers of the corresponding blocksystems $B_i$ : $$G=\bigcap S^{B_i}$$

First i thought, it is sufficient that the selected subgroups $U_i$ have trivial intersection and that there union generates $G$, but i found a counterexample.

If anyone had an idea i would be grateful.

Comment: There are many $G$ that are not such an intersection. I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: Is there a sufficient criterium, when it is possible?

Comment: I don't see any reason why one would think it is possible. It happens to work for the following groups: C1, C2, C2xC2, S3, D8, E8, and D10, but it does not work for C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C4xC2, Q8, C9, C3xC3, C10, nor C11.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that a finite group which is generated by elements of order two is the intersection of such stabilizers. Every finite simple non-abelian group falls into that class of groups I think. But I am not sure how relevant this is for the theory of finite groups.